# Python dropping white space

Tags: python

I am using a csv file that I am iterating over each line and make each column a different title.

```
for i in csvreader:
    1 = i[0]
    2 = i[1]
```

etc.

however the 2 column has spaces after the text in the column 'text    '. I need to removed the spaces after the text. I need 'text', with no spaces at the end.

I know I could just remove it from the CSV in excel, but I need to do this with Python I am not wanting to open CSV file and work with it.

I have tried to `replace` and `strip`, but I can't get this to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) (or `lstrip()` or `rstrip()`):

```
col2 = i[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
with open('some.csv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin):
    for row in csvin:
        cols = [col.strip() for col in row]
        pass # whatever
```